# compile java with external jar file in terminal

Tags: java, compilation

Hi I want to compile java code in the terminal I enter the below command in terminal

```
javac -cp .:../../lucene-8.6.3/lucene-8.6.3/core/lucene-core-8.6.3.jar:../../lucene-8.6.3/lucene-8.6.3/analysis/common/lucene-analyzers-common-8.6.3.jar:../../lucene-8.6.3/lucene-8.6.3/queryparser/lucene-queryparser-8.6.3.jar IndexFiles.java
```

and i dont get any error, and after i enter below command to run:

```
java -cp .:../../lucene-8.6.3/lucene-8.6.3/core/lucene-core-8.6.3.jar:../../lucene-8.6.3/lucene-8.6.3/analysis/common/lucene-analyzers-common-8.6.3.jar:../../lucene-8.6.3/lucene-8.6.3/queryparser/lucene-queryparser-8.6.3.jar IndexFiles
```

but I get this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class IndexFiles
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: lucene/IndexFiles (wrong name: IndexFiles)
```

what should I do? and what is my wrong?

and this is IndexFiles class

```
package lucene;

import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.document.*;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode;
import org.apache.lucene.index.Term;
import org.apache.lucene.store.Directory;
import org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;
import java.util.Date;

/** Index all text files under a directory.
 * <p>
 * This is a command-line application demonstrating simple Lucene indexing.
 * Run it with no command-line arguments for usage information.
 */
public class IndexFiles {
    ....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your class is in the package `lucene`, that’s the class name that you need to pass to `java`: it requires the *fully qualified name*.

```sh
CLASSPATH=../../lucene-8.6.3/lucene-8.6.3/core/lucene-core-8.6.3.jar:../../lucene-8.6.3/lucene-8.6.3/analysis/common/lucene-analyzers-common-8.6.3.jar:../../lucene-8.6.3/lucene-8.6.3/queryparser/lucene-queryparser-8.6.3.jar
java -cp ".:$CLASSPATH" lucene.IndexFiles
```

You’ll also need to make sure that the `.class` file is actually at the right location. In your case, that would be `./lucene/IndexFiles.class`.

Comment: is it possible to write complete command to i enter in terminal i am not profesional in java?thanks

Comment: @fahimjafari OK, the command is complete now. These are two separate commands which you enter one after the other on the command line

Comment: error changed to this one: Error: Unable to initialize main class lucene.IndexFiles
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/analysis/Analyzer

Comment: and when i run this project in intellij it runs, but i need to run this in terminal

Comment: thank you Konrad Rudolph i accepted your answer, but if you know what should i do with this new error, please help me /\

Comment: it is solved, the reason was i forgot to add .java to IndexFiles